# Как импортировать файл из reactjs в nodejs для дальнейшей работы?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, express

Мне надо чтобы excel файл загружался через web интерфейс reactjs и потом обрабатывал его nodejs. Потом после загрузки nodejs конвертирует excel файл в json и загружает его в массив.

Мне надо чтоб при загрузке файла, reactjs привязывал файл к переменной которую потом nodejs будет использовать в дальнейшей работе.

Comment: exel - это excel? Тебе нужно просто перекинуть файл екселя на сервер? Можно через Content-Type: multipart-data и на сервере принимать (к примеру multer) потом уже просто возвращать json

Comment: В браузере делаете форму с помощью которой пользователь может указать файл на ПК. Считываете его, отправляете на сервер и работаете с ним, в чем проблема.

Comment: @RTW Загрузку я уже реализовал. Как сделать так, чтобы клиентская часть прикрепила файл к переменной, с которой потом могла работать серверная часть.

Comment: @kitsoRik Загрузку файла я реализовал. Мне надо чтобы reactjs привязывал файл к переменной с которой потом nodejs мог работать

Comment: @Los9sh и в чем проблема?

Comment: @RTW Возможно я не так объяснил. Смотри. Проект представляет из себя это. Клиентская часть - reactjs. Серверная - nodejs и связь express. У меня на страницу человек загружает excel файл на сервер в папку. И мне надо чтоб nodejs его подхватывал и из экселевского файла переделывал его в json. И я не знаю как реализовать нормально. 

Есть варик чтоб nodejs постоянно в цикле проверял на наличие файла в папке. Но это не катит. Как мне сделать, чтобы react передавал имя файла в nodejs и потом он работал с ним.

Comment: В чем проблема тригерить событие на сервере в момент загрузки файла?

Comment: @RTW Я в этом новичок, расскажи подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: @Los9sh чтобы рассказать точнее, предоставьте кусочки кода, как вы загружаете файл и в какой переменной вам нужно чтобы файл оказался.

Comment: @Los9sh зачем там цикл? Файл пришел -> сделал из него JSON -> Отправил обратно (или что там) -> Удалил файл, где тут цикл?